# Jinja: if path == '/home' or '/home/<int>'

Tags: jinja2

I am interested in knowing the proper way of performing the following function:

```
<li {% if request.path == '/' or '/<int> %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
```

The above does work however, if one visits a url such as '/article/3' or '/anything/', the 'active' class is triggered as well.

I had tried the following:

```
<li {% if request.path == '/<int> %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i> Home</a></li>
```

The integer is representing a page number which is set to 1 by default.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to perform this task the long/verbose way:

Example:

```py
{% if request.path == '/' %}
<a href="/" class="item active">Home</a>
{% else %}
<a href="/" class="item">Home</a>
{% endif %}
```